# I am not able to access UID in firebase on other HTML pages than login page

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);  

  const auth = firebase.auth();

 function signUp(){

          var email = document.getElementById("emailsu");
          var password = document.getElementById("passwordsu");

          const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
          promise.catch(e => alert(e.message));
          alert("Signed Up");
  }
  

  function signIn(){

    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");

    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
    promise.catch(e => alert(e.message));

}

 

    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
      if(user){
        window.location.assign("Landing Page"); 
      }else{
            //no user is signed in
      }
    });


function signOut(){
  auth.signOut();
  alert("Signed Out");
  window.location.replace("index.html");
}
```

This is my authentication JavaScript And when I tried to link this file using script tag to access UID pages other than login page... It starts to reload recursively... I want to Access UIDs and save them in database as DOCUMENT name so I can fetch the data using UID of the user

the folder contains 6 Different HTML pages but it only authenticates the **login page**

Comment: ok, so just to be clear, what you want to achieve is: when the user is created here `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`, you want to get it's uid and create a firestore document with it so it can be accessed in different pages of your app. Is that it? If yes, is the uid the only thing you are storing in that document?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that and so , The document contains the a lot of info like address and contact information and etc. I have archived 2 things, 1> Creating user through Firebase Auth 2> Getting information from the Forms and Inserting it into the DB. Now I just want that When the user is created, The UID of the User = The Document  ID he creates through the form. So that whenever the user logs in , That document is fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do it after the promise of `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` has been fulfilled, which will return you a `UserCredentials` object which contains the uid you want, and then you can create a document in Firestore with that, like this:

```
const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
                    .then(function(userCredential) {
                        firestore.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user.uid).set({
                            email: email.value
                        })
                    })
```

With that approach the uid of that document will be the same as the uid of the auth credentials, however, because you will be using the same value you will have to set the document with some other value since no document can be created empty. Since email was available and it is a user information that can be added to the document I used that variable and you can add more information later in your app's execution.

Also make sure to initialize the Firestore as well with:

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but its not working., When I add this to the code, It also stops to sign up... It do not give any error but stops signing up

Comment: Are you using a new email for the that? If the user was already created before it will not work and this can be the case since the users you were testing before were created, the only thing that was not created was the firestore document.